# Using Screen to keep process running

Tags: gnu-screen

So I have a domain and I need to keep a python process running after I exit my ssh session. Right now, when I exit, it goes poof.

I was told to use Screen, but am fighting with this gnu doc. How would I use Screen to run a python process, and keep it running after I exit my ssh session?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Log on. Run screen. Launch your python program. Press crtl-a crtl-d to detach from your screen. Log out.

Log in again. screen -r to reattach to your process.

Answer (score 2):

Although I love GNU Screen the classical solution for this is `nohup`, which is much more straightforward and equally useful *if* you don't ever need to reattach to the process.

`nohup script.py` should be enough. The process output gets saved to a file in the current directory.